# running python flask app with virtual environment (VENV) on VPS in background

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, python

I am trying to run a flask app on my VPS in production environment. The problem is that I can't alter any of the VPS packages, and it uses a `python3.5` interpreter as default. The version that is needed for my App to work is `python3.6`or more.

The solution was to use a virtual environment to make the necessary dependencies available without touching those of the OS.

my question is how do I activate `venv` and run my flask app in a service fashion (start and stop). the commands that I use to start my app are simple :

```
source venv/bin/activate
FLASK_APP=app.py flask run --host 0.0.0.0
```

**Note :** My VPS runs ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, which is To use the symlink created by the adding of the virtual environment of the python version I need.

so having

`ExecStart=/root/project/venv/bin/python3.6 -m flask run`

and specifying the environment variable :

`Environment=FLASK_APP=app.py`

also the working directory (needed to recognize the app.py)

all in a systemd service file did the trick.